# How many CPU will a multithreaded application take, if runs in multicore processor

Tags: java, multithreading

A multi-core processor is a single computing component with two or more independent actual central processing units (called "cores"), which are the units that read and execute program instructions.

If a multithreaded application runs on a multi-core processor, how many CPUs will is use? For example, if the machine is capable of dual core execution, then 2 CPUs will be used, if my understanding is correct. Within these two CPUs, multiple threads will be executed and do the context switching.

Comment: If you have two threads but they are not busy at the same time, the OS may use only one core.  If you have one thread, it may switch between the two cores over time.  i.e. it all depends.

Comment: Please note that your application runs within `JVM`. So JVM will be responsible for actual CPU utilization.

Comment: @Thanks All, for your valuable Answers.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> If a Mulithreaded application runs on multi-core processor, how many CPU it will use, for example if the machine is capable of doing the dualcore, then 2 CPU will be used is my understanding is correct, and within these two CPU multiple thread will be executed and do the context switching.

The JVM really doesn't deal directly with processors.  It uses the native thread capabilities of the operating system which uses the processors that are exposed by the operating system and hardware.  In Java there is a `Runtime.availableProcessors()` method but this in a only a few places by the JVM code.

To the JVM or any other application running on a computer, the multiple cores typically seem the same as multiple processors if that's how the OS exposes them.  This means that the distinction between physical processors versus multiple cores in a single processor is completely hidden from the Java programmer.

There are single core CPUs then there are CPUs with multiple cores which share certain internal components but the OS sees them and schedules them as multiple processors.  Multiple cores are most likely seen to the OS as multiple CPUs -- there is no distinction.  Then there are the virtual processors often called [hyperthreading](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperthreading) which share the same processor *core* (and the associated processing circuitry) but have multiple execution pipelines. These are also (usually) seen by the OS as multiple processors.

Specifically, in the OP's example, you have a single processor with two cores, in linux cat'ing `/proc/cpuinfo` will show 2 processors and in Java the `Runtime.availableProcessors()` will return 2.  It will also return 2 if you have 2 physical processors also will most likely if you have a single core with dual hyperthreading pipelines depending on the OS kernel.

As to how many processors the JVM will *actually* be using, this depends again on the native thread code.  This said, if the JVM is running on a single CPU with two cores, and the cores are not in use by other applications or the OS, then the JVM's thread will most likely be scheduled to run on them concurrently.

Comment: Thanks It means JVM Sees multi*core* CPU has multiple execution cores one one CPU,

Comment: and in case of multiprocessor system contains more than one such CPU, the same concept should apply ?

Comment: @anish The JVM doesn't see anything. It creates a native thread when you create a thread in Java and less the OS deal with it.  The only clue the JVM has is Runtime.availableProcessors() otherwise it is none the wiser.

Answer (score 2):

By default you can utilize all processors. One processor can run **virtually** as many threads as possible at the same time (virtually means that physically there's always just one thread which is running). How many is possible depends on the operating system resource limitations and the used threading framework.

It doesn't matter from software point of view, if the cores are on one die, and there's one CPU socket with a multi-core CPU, or there are more CPU sockets. The OS and JVM will see the collection of the cores. (This brings in an interesting aspect though: data exchange between such cores which are on the same die and those which are in different sockets are not uniform).

Thread schedulers (talking about both the OS's and the virtual machine's) often tend to shuffle and move threads from one core to another throughout scheduler time. That can hurt performance, there are techniques to tie a thread to a certain core (thread affinity).

Comment: One processor (physical or virtual) can only run one thread at one time.

Comment: Notice the word **virtually**. I'll bold it in my post too.

Comment: I thought that's obvious, like with multi-taksing operating systems on singe cores: there's only one task which runs at one time. With SMT (simultaneous multi threading) technologies like Hyper-Threading the **virtually** is just semi true. If a one core have SMT built-in for two threads, it kinda can run two threads at the same time. In this case the OS sees the core as two cores.

Answer (score 1):

How much cpu resources your application (lets assume long running task) will really consume depends on how much percentage you need your cpu. Application can be network, memory, harddisk or cpu bound and a few others.

If the cpu has to wait for any other resource such as memory or network it will remain idle or be assigned to other threads.

**Example:**

If your application is only cpu bound (won't consume much memory) and you run a long task with as many threads as cores (physical or virtual with hyperthreading) you will get almost 100% usage of the free resources that are not used by other running threads (os, programms).

Depending on the program you can tell in which state your application is from the cpu/memory/network consumption and you can analyse the performance.

Answer (score 1):

It will get use of at most as many CPUs as you have simultaneously busy threads, and possibly as few as one.

Answer (score 0):

From programmer's point of view, a core is a processor. Method [Runtime.availableProcessors()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html#availableProcessors%28%29) shows the number of cores. However, from manufacturer's point of view, multi-core processor is similar to ordinary processor, so they decided to leave the name "processor", probably making a marketing mistake.

Comment: This is somewhat misleading.  `Runtime.availableProcessors()` shows the number of processors available to the JVM -- either physical or virtual.  A multi-core process is not "similar" to an "ordinary" processor, nor is it a marketing mistake.  It's about what the OS presents to applications as opposed to the true hardware configuration.  A core is seen the JVM as a physical processor and the distinction between a core and a processor is hidden.

Comment: @Gray in other words, you consider manufacturer's terminology  correct and programmer's terminology wrong. I'd like to see prooflinks, at least proof that core is virtual processor. I think core is a real processor, while example of virtual processor is a Thread.

Comment: #sysctl hw.ncpu | awk '{print $2}'
8                                                                   int availableProcessors = Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors();                         8

Comment: I'm not saying that a core is virtual but it is different than a full processor.  Cores share certain components and are similar but not equal to a single processor.  But the OS hides these differences to the software and the JVM hides the distinction even more.  Examples of a virtual processor is one that supports hyperthreading.  These are single core processors with multiple execution pipelines that are usually seen by the OS, again, as multiple processors.